# Does any subset of $\mathbb{R}$ has an l.u.b?

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

In theorem $2$ of chapter $1$ of *Real Mahtematical Analysis*, by Chalrles C. Pugh, the author proves the existence of a least upper bound of any bounded subset $\mathbb{C}$ of $\mathbb{R}$ (which has been constructed by Dedekind's cuts already). In the proof, the author considers the cut $C\mid D$ where $C = \{a\in \mathbb{R}:a\in A$ for at least one $A\in \mathbb{C}\}$, $D=\mathbb{Q}-C$. Then he argues that $C$ is an upper bound for $\mathbb{C}$ because, (because of the construction), for any $A\in \mathbb{C}$, $A\subset C$. Then $C$ is proved to be the smallest upper bound by showing that any other upper bound must contain $C$ as well.

My confusion with this argument is that if we have used the fact that $\mathbb{C}$ is bounded above at all. Does it not follow from the aforementioned argument that any subset of $\mathbb{R}$ has an upper bound and has a least upper bound?

Comment: Using $\;\Bbb C\;$ for anything but the complex numbers can be highly confusing...and your definition of $\;C\;$ looks pretty fishy. Check this.

Comment: Boundedness is used to prove that $D$ is not empty. If $D$ is empty, then $C\mid D$ is not a cut.

Comment: What's the least upper bound of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @egreg Answered my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument works up to a small, but essential, detail: in order that a set such as your $C$ is (the lower part of) a Dedekind cut, its complement $D=\mathbb{Q}\setminus C$ *must not* be empty.

Only if the subset $\mathcal{X}$ of $\mathbb{R}$ you start with is upper bounded you can conclude that, setting
$$
C=\{a\in\mathbb{Q}: \text{$a\in A$, for some $A\in \mathcal{X}$}\}
$$
is a properly defined Dedekind cut, in particular that $D=\mathbb{Q}\setminus C$ is not empty.

<sup>Note that $C$ must be a subset of $\mathbb{Q}$, not of $\mathbb{R}$ as you write.</sup>

Namely, if $r$ is an upper bound for $\mathcal{X}$, then $r$ is defined by a Dedekind cut $E\mid F$ and you should be able to prove that, for every $b\in F$, $b\notin C$.

Conversely, if $\mathcal{X}$ is not upper bounded, then you should be able to prove that $C=\mathbb{Q}$.